# Why does assignment of `uint8_t` to `uint8_t` give conversion warning?

Tags: c, type-conversion

Why is this piece of C code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t do_foo() {
  uint8_t int8;
  int8 = 0x80;
  int8 = int8 + (uint8_t) 1;
  return int8;
}
```

giving this compiler warning?

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
$ gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion test.c
test.c: In function ‘do_foo’:
test.c:6:10: warning: conversion to ‘uint8_t’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
   int8 = int8 + (uint8_t) 1;
          ^
```

As far as I can see, the expression on the right is most definitely of type `uint8_t`, and not of type `int`.

Comment: The problem is with the return of `do_foo()`. It returns an int, this is what generates the warning. So in the return statement, uint8_t is implicitly converted to the return type of do_foo(), namely an int! Edit: Sorry, that is a different problem, the 1 literal is an int, and int is a 32 bit type. So the int will be downcasted to the uint8. Unfortunately I can't get to a compiler right now but I guess that's what wrong.

Comment: @mvdwerve: Sorry, but I think you are wrong. gcc knows the value of the literal (`1`), so there is no reason to believe the conversion ("down-cast") alters the value.

Comment: @undur_gongor You're probably right, and I see your answer regarding integer promotion, which I didn't even think of! Forgot about that dodgier side of C. Sorry, I was wrong.

Comment: There is no problem with your code. gcc is over-zealous in its warnings, the conversion may *not* alter the value in your code.

Answer (score 6):

This is due to integer promotion.

The operands of `+` are smaller than `int`. Therefore, they are promoted to `int` and the addition is carried out in `int`.

For the assignment to `int8`, the result has to be converted back to `uint8_t` causing the warning because the value might not fit.

Comment: So, in other words, I can *never* assign *anything* to a variable of type `uint_8` without getting a warning, because any expression will always be promoted to (at least) `int`?

Comment: @Nikratio Does `int8 = (uint8_t)(int8 + 1);` give a warning?

Comment: @immibis No, but that would also most definitely be a bug.

Comment: @Nikratio Why would it be a bug?

Answer (score 5):

In order to simplify compilers, C as originally defined only allowed arithmetic on five numeric types: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, and `double`, thus meaning that compilers only had to know five ways to perform each arithmetic operator.  Further, on two's-complement systems, many of the operators can use the same implementation for both signed and unsigned integer types, and thus only need three implementations.  Attempts to perform arithmetic upon any type other than one of the above, or on any combination of types, will result in "both" operands being converted to the same type from the above list [the right-hand operator of left-shift and right-shift types is independent of the left].

Although the Standard has since changed to add `float` to the list of types upon which arithmetic may be performed, your example uses type `uint8_t`, which is not on that list.  In general, values of types not on the list are converted to the first type on the list which can hold all values of the corresponding type, which in your case would be `int`.  Having promoted both operands to the addition to type `int` and performing the addition, the compiler then complains when an attempt is made to assign the result back to a smaller type.